# c# MailMessage different country language

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to set the mail message body of an html email to a different language im using

```
   MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
   msg.BodyEncoding = Encoder ?????
```

thanks

Comment: `msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` ? Not sure what you mean by different language

Comment: Im trying to encode it for Russian to start with

Comment: This should work, try it out

Comment: One thing is also importent to know here that C# default encoding is Unicode and not UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding is not about language, but about [character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). C# uses UTF16 internally, so if you set your encoding to UTF, you should be able to write any text you want as UTF can express any character of any set. That's what [UNICODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) is used for.

Answer (score 1):

Look to this info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

As @SriramSakthivel mention in his comment you can do it:

UTF-8 Encoding support all language what you need!

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
{
  From = new MailAddress("My@MyMail.com", "Test"),
  BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
  Body = body,
  IsBodyHtml = true,
  ReplyTo = new MailAddress("Someone@Test.com"),
  SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
}
```